# Can't find module 'hbs' with ES6 style import

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript1.6

I'm doing this in TypeScript, but tried it in vanilla JS as well with the same error. I've pulled down two modules: **express** and **hbs**. I'm trying to use the ES6 `import` syntax like this:

```
import * as http from 'http';
import * as express from 'express';
import hbs from 'hbs';
```

The last line gives me an error saying it can't find module **hbs**. I'm looking right at it... I can see it just fine. However when I replace the line with the older CommonJS syntax:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
```

It works fine... what gives? Still on the learning curve with ES6...

Comment: have you tried `import {hbs} from 'hbs';`?

Comment: Yup... the error is always on the `'hbs'` part (the right side where you specify the module name)... it always says it can't find the module.

Comment: Interesting, can you post the code in hbs that exports the module?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiecing a similar problem. The syntax is correct ES6 indeed. 
Good news is that the problem seems to have been fixed already in the development version of the typescript compiler 0.8: try 'npm install typescript@next -g' and then running the compiler again.

Answer (score 1):

Observation 1... as you have in your other exports, you should either import the whole module with an alias:

```
import * as hbs from 'hbs';
```

Or you can choose to import specific exports:

```
import {thing} from 'hbs';
```

Observation 2... is `hbs` a TypeScript module, or a JavaScript one? If it is a JavaScript one (as I believe it may be) you will need to pair it with a definition file, for example `hbs.d.ts` that describes the JavaScript file. TypeScript won't recognise a plain JavaScript module without the definition.

Comment: It's a JS library without an associated type definition... but i know that's not required. I can use this syntax to import ExpressJS which is a JS library and have no problems. 

I tried the two other syntaxes and they didn't work either. It's something about not being able to "see" the library hbs like it isn't there.

Comment: You know that a type definition isn't required? At the moment the compiler seems to agree with me :)

Comment: Not sure I understand your response... If I remove my type def for Express it works.

Answer (score 0):

you should use default as the imported module name .

```
import {default as hbs} from "hbs";
```

this works same as

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
```

because require("hbs") imports default module  exported by hbs.